# How can I configure NetBeans to show source and design views on separate monitors?

Tags: netbeans

Is it possible to configure NetBeans on a multi-monitor system such that one monitor shows source, and another shows design? How?

Comment: Sorry i don't understand

Comment: I think Michael understood and he edited your answer to remove the inappropriate tags.

Comment: Ok, sorry for problems :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something similar will be supported in NB74.
See http://wiki.netbeans.org/wiki/images/9/91/Horizontal_split.png

Not as separate windows, but next to each other.

Answer (score 0):

There is small cross icon in the upper right corner.

Drag it and split